# Approach to create a filtering function for list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, dictionary

I have an extensive list of dictionaries with the following structure:

```
data1 = 
[{'_id': '4nPkqDbLZU',
      'data_Temperature': 14,
      'data_time_utc': 1403560800,
      'location_0': 9.6071829,
      'data_Rain': 0,
      'modules_0': '02:00:00:00:0b:60',
      'modules_1': '05:00:00:01:3c:5c',
      'location_1': 55.726223,
      'altitude': 74},
     {'_id': '4nPkqDbL855',
      'data_Temperature': 29,
      'data_time_utc': 1403560900,
      'location_0': 9.6071829,
      'data_Rain': 0,
      'modules_0': '02:00:00:00:0b:60',
      'modules_1': '05:00:00:01:3c:5c',
      'location_1': 55.726223,
      'altitude': 74},]
```

And I created the following code to only select the data I need and rename the dictionary keys at the same time:

```
d1 = []
for x in data1:
        data_dict = {
            "id":          x.get('_id'),
            "Temperature": x.get('data_Temperature'),
            "time_utc":    x.get('data_time_utc'),
            "longitude":   x.get('location_0'),
            "latitude":    x.get('location_1'),
            "altitude":    x.get('altitude'),
        }
        d1.append(data_dict)
```

It works fine, but I need to execute the same instruction for many other list of dictionaries. So I think the way to go is to wrap the code in a function. I tried different ways but I'm not succeeding. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a function which returns a list, using a list comprehension. This will be more efficient than a manual `for` loop or a functional solution via `map`.

```
def reformat_dict(d):
    return [{"id":          x.get('_id'),
             "Temperature": x.get('data_Temperature'),
             "time_utc":    x.get('data_time_utc'),
             "longitude":   x.get('location_0'),
             "latitude":    x.get('location_1'),
             "altitude":    x.get('altitude')}
            for item in d]

res = reformat_dict(data1)

print(res)

[{'Temperature': 29,
  'altitude': 74,
  'id': '4nPkqDbL855',
  'latitude': 55.726223,
  'longitude': 9.6071829,
  'time_utc': 1403560900},
 {'Temperature': 29,
  'altitude': 74,
  'id': '4nPkqDbL855',
  'latitude': 55.726223,
  'longitude': 9.6071829,
  'time_utc': 1403560900}]
```

Comment: Thanks @jpp It works just fine. I'm selecting this as the answer since this was exactly what I was trying before, but my formatting was wrong. And for me this way is more readable.

Answer (score 3):

One approach using `lambda` and `map`

**Demo:**

```
makeDict = lambda x: {
            "id":          x.get('_id'),
            "Temperature": x.get('data_Temperature'),
            "time_utc":    x.get('data_time_utc'),
            "longitude":   x.get('location_0'),
            "latitude":    x.get('location_1'),
            "altitude":    x.get('altitude'),
            }

print( list(map(makeDict, data1)) )
```

**Output:**

```
[{'Temperature': 14, 'time_utc': 1403560800, 'altitude': 74, 'longitude': 9.6071829, 'latitude': 55.726223, 'id': '4nPkqDbLZU'}, {'Temperature': 29, 'time_utc': 1403560900, 'altitude': 74, 'longitude': 9.6071829, 'latitude': 55.726223, 'id': '4nPkqDbL855'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want some freedom to call such a function, you can factorize it like below :

```
def filter_dict(dict_list, **kwargs):
    return [{key:dic.get(val) for key, val in kwargs.items() } 
                for dic in dict_list ]
```

The function take the list of dict as a first parameter, then all the keys you want as keywords, to match the new names :

```
print(filter_dict(data1, 
                  id='_id', 
                  Temperature='data_Temperature',
                  time_utc='data_time_utc' ))  

>>>[{'id': '4nPkqDbLZU', 'Temperature': 14, 'time_utc': 1403560800}, 
    {'id': '4nPkqDbL855', 'Temperature': 29, 'time_utc': 1403560900}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mapping = dict(id='_id', Temperature='data_Temperature', time_utc='data_time_utc',
               longitude='location_0', latitude='location_1', altitude='altitude')
nd = list(map(lambda d: {k: d.get(mapping[k], '') for k,v in mapping.items()}, data1))
pprint(nd)
```

Output:

```
[{'Temperature': 14,
  'altitude': 74,
  'id': '4nPkqDbLZU',
  'latitude': 55.726223,
  'longitude': 9.6071829,
  'time_utc': 1403560800},
 {'Temperature': 29,
  'altitude': 74,
  'id': '4nPkqDbL855',
  'latitude': 55.726223,
  'longitude': 9.6071829,
  'time_utc': 1403560900}]
```